# Для чего нужен bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Интересует для чего нужен баш (shell?). Как его используют?
Это крутая оболочка! Правильно ли я понимаю, что не стоит писать на ней скрипты, требующие высокого уровня безопасности?

Если мне нужно создать пользователя с определенными параметрами и несколько директорий для него, при этом, имя пользователя и пароль будут входящими данными от пользователей извне (например из веб-интерфейса), мне не стоит использовать для этого баш скрипт? Ведь он будет исполняться от привилегированного пользователя, а значит при недостаточной фильтрации данных, будет уязвимым местом системы. А фильтровать данные в нем мне показалось неудобным.

Ну или например использовать этот скрипт после проверки данных вне bash, более привычным мне способом. Ведь в bash все довольно хардкорно и лично я предпочел бы проверять валидность данных в питоне/java/php, потому что лучше знаю функции этих языков и лучше понимаю их логику.

Лично меня пугает что баш может так:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
```

(первый аргумент скрипта будет интерпретирован как самостоятельная команда с правами пользователя, запустившего скрипт)

В общем объясните для чего нужен баш и как НЕ СЛЕДУЕТ его использовать.

Comment: @jfs вопрос вполне конкретный. Я не знаю для чего обычно используют баш. Обычно я занимаюсь программированием на языках высокого уровня и система меня не волнует, но сейчас я решил что пора изучить линукс и самостоятельно поднять окружение. Гугл не приводит примеров использования, иначе я бы не пришел сюда с этим вопросом. Я готов засчитать как ответ, комментарий с точной поисковой фразой (одной или несколькими), если результаты поиска дадут ответы на поставленный мной вопрос. Иначе, совет "иди в гугл" слишком общий, этот сайт призван помогать новичкам, а не посылать их в гугл

Comment: Иначе, если в ответ на любой вопрос очевидный опытным пользователям, можно всегда посылать всех в гугл, то этот сайт не имеет смысла. Если бы я знал что именно загуглить и нашел бы ответ в гугле, я бы не дошел до прямого вопроса сообществу. Если я не могу нагуглить ответ, значит он не доступен для пользователей вроде меня, значит вопрос нужно обсудить под более очевидными ключевыми словами. Гугл - всего лишь машина для поиска по контексту, я не могу задать ей дополнительный вопрос или спросить о личном опыте использования

Comment: Он нужен как в процессе [загрузки системы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), так и для удобства работы пользователей. Большинство утилит и средства, которые предоставляет bash для их запуска и совместной работы, достаточно хорошо продуманы. Поскольку bash это чистый интерпретатор, то не следует его использовать для вычислений и достаточно интенсивной обработки данных (используйте подходящие команды (или свои программы) и bash в качестве "клея" для их результатов)

Answer (score 1):

> Для чего нужен баш

Для того, чтобы **автоматизировать некоторые действия**. Наверно, это основное его применение.

Допустим, вам нужно что-то установить на линух и настроить. Конечно, можно набирать команду за командой вручную. Но что стоит разработчику софта приложить вместе со своим продуктом скрипт установки? И вам меньше возни.

Или же вам нужно поднимать сервер, но для этого приходится делать какое-то количество последовательных действий. Лучше ведь записать все в файлик и воспроизвести его за секунду?

> Как не следует использовать

Писать игры, наверно? (Интересно, есть ли игры на баше?)

А если без шуток, то тут уже дело вкуса. Кто-то пишет на нем какие-то простые вспомогательные утилиты. Кто-то считает медленным и пишет подобное на Питоне. Всему своё место и применение, как говорится.

Кстати. Ответ не претендует быть правильным и единственно верным. Это лишь моё видение. Удачи вам.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79923/discussion-on-answer-by-selya----bash).

Comment: Тетрис на *sed* есть.